# XML Extension not found

Tags: php, centos, php-extension

I have centos 6.5 server and when I try to install php extension using `pecl` I get the following error:

```
XML Extension not found
```

All the documentations say that this extension is included by default... Why this error still exists?

Comment: check your php.ini file and see if the XML extension is disabled by ";"

Answer (score 3):

According to [a comment on php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php#102046)

> Certain Linux distributions do not have this extension included in the minimum PHP package. It can usually be found in one of the "optional" php-* packages.
>
> For CentOS, you will need to run `yum install php-xml`, which provides this extension.

So please try to install it using:

```
yum install php-xml
```

Also check your <kbd>php.ini</kbd> and make sure that the extension is not commented out with a `;` it should be listed as:

```
extension=dom.so
```

In order to be absolutely sure whether or not a module is *enabled* you should use `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 and phpV7.4 perfectly work. Try this one

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```